# How to use Assert.Catch with an async method

Tags: c#, async-await, nunit-3.0

I just upgraded to NUnit 3, and I'm having some trouble getting my unit tests to pass.

```
[Test]
public void GetSomethingAsync_CallsConverter()
{
    int id = 123;

    Assert.Catch<NullReferenceException>(
        async () => await _repository.GetSomethingAsync(id));

    _fooMock.Verify(f => f.Bar(id), Times.Once);
}
```

NUnit gives me this error:

> System.ArgumentException : 'async void' methods are not supported, please use 'async Task' instead

I managed to get my `Assert.Throws` to pass by changing it like this:

```
    Assert.Throws<NullReferenceException>(
        async () => await _repository.GetSomethingAsync(id));
//to
    Assert.That(
        async () => await _repository.GetSomethingAsync(id),
        Throws.InstanceOf<NullReferenceException>());
```

But there's no similar equivalent thing to `Assert.Catch`.
So how are we supposed to use `Assert.Catch` on async methods?

Comment: It turns out that I had misunderstood Assert.Catch vs Assert.Throws so this question does not make that much sense. But the answers are useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I replaced the void return with Task so

Try replacing

```
[Test]
public void GetSomethingAsync_CallsConverter()
```

with

```
[Test]
public async Task GetSomethingAsync_CallsConverter()
```

So here is a example of how we are testing async calls

```
[Test]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Integration_Get_Invalid_ReturnsUnauthorized()
{
    // ARRANGE
    const string url = "/api/v2/authenticate/999/wrongName/wrongPassword";

    // ACT
    var result = await Get(url);

    // ASSERT
    Assert.IsFalse(result.HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode); 
}
```

If you want to test that an exception is being raised use the following

```
Assert.Throws<ValidationException>(() =>
{
    var user = await _service.Get(2);
 });
```

Comment: OK but in my scenario the `Get` method sometimes throws an exception, and so I want to assert that a specific exception was thrown and also that another method was called. I'm not sure this is possible in NUnit 3.0.

Comment: It is possible check out Assert.Throws

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood Assert.Catch vs Assert.Throws. The only syntax I could get working is like this `Assert.That(async () => await _repository.GetSomethingAsync(id), Throws.TypeOf<NullReferenceException>());
` -- and only if my unit test returns `void` and not marked async. But as @StephenCleary says the syntax you described should be fixed soon in NUnit 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

I use my own [`AssertEx.ThrowsAsync` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx), since various unit testing frameworks / assertion libraries have varying amounts of support for `async`:

```
[Test]
public async Task GetSomethingAsync_CallsConverter()
{
  int id = 123;

  await AssertEx.ThrowsAsync<NullReferenceException>(
      async () => await _repository.GetSomethingAsync(id));

  _fooMock.Verify(f => f.Bar(id), Times.Once);
}
```

A [fix is coming](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/464) for NUnit. Unfortunately, they've chosen to implement it with a sync-over-async pattern, which I believe is a mistake that will come back to bite them later.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the NUnit discussion. I did search for something similar but didn't spot it. Looks like my best option would be to wait for NUnit 3.2 which should be released within the month.

Comment: ThrowsAsync<> is still completely broken in NUnit 3.6 :-(